# Same classification given for neural network regardless of the input

Tags: python, neural-network, classification, keras, tensorflow

I am using the MNIST classification tutorials on the TensorFlow website to create my own classification program to predict a footballers value using the FIFA 19 dataset. However, when I run my program, it always picks the same classification for every player in my testing dataset even when the players should have different values. I checked the probabilities that were predicted in the last layer of the neural network which has the probabilities for each classification and it shows that all probabilities are 0 except for one, which is the class that is predicted for all players. How do I fix this?

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

# import numpy library
import numpy as np

# import pandas library
import pandas as pd

# import seaborn library
import seaborn as sns

# import pyplot library
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# store directory containing data in a variable
DATAPATH = '../../Data/fifa19/dataNumerical.csv'
VALUES = '../../Data/fifa19/player values for classification.csv'

# import the dataset using pandas
def init_column_names():
    columnNames = ['Age',
                   'CountryWorldRankingPoints',
                   'Overall',
                   'Potential',
                   'ClubGoals',
                   'Value(€M)',
                   'Wage(€K)',
                   'Special',
                   'PreferredFoot',
                   'InternationalReputation',
                   'WeakFoot',
                   'SkillMoves',
                   'WorkRate',
                   'BodyType',
                   'Position',
                   'JerseyNumber',
                   'Height(cm)',
                   'Weight(lbs)',
                   'LS',
                   'ST',
                   'RS',
                   'LW',
                   'LF',
                   'CF',
                   'RF',
                   'RW',
                   'LAM',
                   'CAM',
                   'RAM',
                   'LM',
                   'LCM',
                   'CM',
                   'RCM',
                   'RM',
                   'LWB',
                   'LDM',
                   'CDM',
                   'RDM',
                   'RWB',
                   'LB',
                   'LCB',
                   'CB',
                   'RCB',
                   'RB',
                   'Crossing',
                   'Finishing',
                   'HeadingAccuracy',
                   'ShortPassing',
                   'Volleys',
                   'Dribbling',
                   'Curve',
                   'FKAccuracy',
                   'LongPassing',
                   'BallControl',
                   'Acceleration',
                   'SprintSpeed',
                   'Agility',
                   'Reactions',
                   'Balance',
                   'ShotPower',
                   'Jumping',
                   'Stamina',
                   'Strength',
                   'LongShots',
                   'Aggression',
                   'Interceptions',
                   'Positioning',
                   'Vision',
                   'Penalties',
                   'Composure',
                   'Marking',
                   'StandingTackle',
                   'SlidingTackle',
                   'GKDiving',
                   'GKHandling',
                   'GKKicking',
                   'GKPositioning',
                   'GKReflexes',
                   'ReleaseClause(€M)'
                   ]
    return columnNames


class_names = ['0-100K', '101-500K', '500K-1M', '1-5M', '5-10M', '10-25M',
               '25-50M', '50-75M', '75-100M', '100M+']

print('==================================================')
print('READ DATA CSV')
column_names = init_column_names()
raw_dataset = pd.read_csv(DATAPATH, names=column_names, na_values="?", comment='\t', sep=",", skipinitialspace=True,
                          encoding='latin-1'
                          )

print('==================================================')
print('READ PLAYER VALUES CSV')
playerValues = pd.read_csv(VALUES, names=['values'], na_values="?", comment='\t', sep=",", skipinitialspace=True,
                           encoding='latin-1'
                           )

# pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 177)
# pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 15)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 5)

# make a copy of the dataset to leave the original unaffected
dataset = raw_dataset.copy()

# clean the dataset by removing unknown values
dataset = dataset.dropna();
# print(type(dataset))

# create classification labels for the dataset
classification_labels = playerValues.values
# print(classification_labels)
# print(type(classification_labels))


# create empty array then append the different classes into the array.
class_labels_array = []
print('==================================================')
print('CREATING CLASS LABELS')
for x in classification_labels:
    if x <= 0.1:
        class_labels_array.append(0)
    elif x < 0.5:
        class_labels_array.append(1)
    elif x < 1:
        class_labels_array.append(2)
    elif x < 5:
        class_labels_array.append(3)
    elif x < 10:
        class_labels_array.append(4)
    elif x < 25:
        class_labels_array.append(5)
    elif x < 50:
        class_labels_array.append(6)
    elif x < 75:
        class_labels_array.append(7)
    elif x < 100:
        class_labels_array.append(8)
    else:
        class_labels_array.append(9)

# print(class_labels_array)
class_labels = pd.DataFrame(data=class_labels_array, columns=['class_labels'])
# print(class_labels)
# print("end of class labels")
# printing the dataset
# print(dataset.tail())


def position_one_hot(dataset):
    position = dataset.pop("Position")
    dataset['CAM'] = (position == 'CAM') * 1.0
    dataset['CB'] = (position == 'CB') * 1.0
    dataset['CDM'] = (position == 'CDM') * 1.0
    dataset['CF'] = (position == 'CF') * 1.0
    dataset['CM'] = (position == 'CM') * 1.0
    dataset['GK'] = (position == 'GK') * 1.0
    dataset['LB'] = (position == 'LB') * 1.0
    dataset['LCB'] = (position == 'LCB') * 1.0
    dataset['LCM'] = (position == 'LCM') * 1.0
    dataset['LDM'] = (position == 'LDM') * 1.0
    dataset['LF'] = (position == 'LF') * 1.0
    dataset['LM'] = (position == 'LM') * 1.0
    dataset['LS'] = (position == 'LS') * 1.0
    dataset['LW'] = (position == 'LW') * 1.0
    dataset['LWB'] = (position == 'LWB') * 1.0
    dataset['RB'] = (position == 'RB') * 1.0
    dataset['RCB'] = (position == 'RCB') * 1.0
    dataset['RCM'] = (position == 'RCM') * 1.0
    dataset['RDM'] = (position == 'RDM') * 1.0
    dataset['RM'] = (position == 'RM') * 1.0
    dataset['RS'] = (position == 'RS') * 1.0
    dataset['RW'] = (position == 'RW') * 1.0
    dataset['RWB'] = (position == 'RWB') * 1.0
    dataset['ST'] = (position == 'ST') * 1.0

    return dataset

# convert the categorical position column into a one-hot.
dataset = position_one_hot(dataset)

# print(dataset.tail())

# print(type(dataset))

# split the data into training and testing datasets.
training_data = dataset.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=0)
print("=============================")
print("TRAINING DATA EXAMPLES")
print(training_data.tail())
testing_data = dataset.drop(training_data.index)
print("=============================")
print("TESTING DATA EXAMPLES")
print(testing_data.tail())

# remove value we are trying to predict from the dataset.
training_data.pop('Value(€M)')
testing_data.pop('Value(€M)')

# split the labels into a training and testing labels.
training_labels = class_labels.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=0)
print("=============================")
print("TRAINING LABELS")
print(training_labels.tail())
testing_labels = class_labels.drop(training_labels.index)
print("=============================")
print("TESTING LABELS")
print(testing_labels.tail())



# new method which can be called to build the model
def buildModel():
    model = keras.Sequential([

        keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[len(training_data.keys())]),
        keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    ])

    # optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


# build the model and store it in a variable.
model = buildModel()

print('==================================================')
print('TRAINING')
# train the model
model.fit(training_data, training_labels, epochs=320, batch_size=32)

print('==================================================')
print('ACCURACY TESTING')
# check accuracy
test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(testing_data, testing_labels)
print('Test accuracy:', test_accuracy)

# make prediction for first player in dataset
predictions = model.predict(testing_data)
# print(predictions[0])
print('==================================================')
print('CLASSIFICATION')

# for x in range(len(predictions)):
for x in range(10):
    # print the strongest class from the prediction
    print('PREDICTION: ', class_names[np.argmax(predictions[x])])

    # print the correct classification of the player that the prediction was made on to see if classification was correct.
    # print(testing_labels.tail())
    print('ACTUAL: ', class_names[int(testing_labels.iloc[x]['class_labels'])])
    print()

print('==================================================')
print('END')
```

**TRAINING AND TESTING OUTPUT**

```
TRAINING
Epoch 1/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 1s - loss: 14.0409 - acc: 0.1250
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 241us/sample - loss: 12.8769 - acc: 0.1965
Epoch 2/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 14.1033 - acc: 0.1250
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.4266 - acc: 0.2274
Epoch 3/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 14.1033 - acc: 0.1250
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 4/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.5923 - acc: 0.2188
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 30us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 5/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 11.5849 - acc: 0.2812
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 6/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 13.0960 - acc: 0.1875
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 30us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 7/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 11.0812 - acc: 0.3125
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 69us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 8/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.5923 - acc: 0.2188
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 30us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 9/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 13.0960 - acc: 0.1875
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 30us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 10/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 14.1033 - acc: 0.1250
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 11/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.0886 - acc: 0.2500
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 12/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 11.0812 - acc: 0.3125
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 13/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 13.0960 - acc: 0.1875
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 14/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 10.5775 - acc: 0.3438
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 15/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 13.5996 - acc: 0.1562
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 16/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.5923 - acc: 0.2188
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 30us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 17/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 11.0812 - acc: 0.3125
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 30us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 18/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.0886 - acc: 0.2500
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 19/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 11.0812 - acc: 0.3125
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 20/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 11.5849 - acc: 0.2812
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 21/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 13.0960 - acc: 0.1875
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 22/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 11.0812 - acc: 0.3125
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 23/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 11.5849 - acc: 0.2812
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 24/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 9.0664 - acc: 0.4375
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 25/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 13.0960 - acc: 0.1875
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 26/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.5923 - acc: 0.2188
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 30us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 27/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.0886 - acc: 0.2500
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 28/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.0886 - acc: 0.2500
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 29/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.5923 - acc: 0.2188
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 30/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.5923 - acc: 0.2188
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 30us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 31/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 10.5775 - acc: 0.3438
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 30us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 32/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.5923 - acc: 0.2188
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 33/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 13.5996 - acc: 0.1562
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 34/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.5923 - acc: 0.2188
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 35/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.0886 - acc: 0.2500
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 36/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.0886 - acc: 0.2500
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 37/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 14.1033 - acc: 0.1250
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 38/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.5923 - acc: 0.2188
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 39/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 13.5996 - acc: 0.1562
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 40/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 14.1033 - acc: 0.1250
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 95us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 41/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 13.0960 - acc: 0.1875
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 42/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 14.1033 - acc: 0.1250
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 43/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 11.0812 - acc: 0.3125
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 44/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 13.0960 - acc: 0.1875
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 45/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 11.5849 - acc: 0.2812
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 30us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 46/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.0886 - acc: 0.2500
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 47/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.5923 - acc: 0.2188
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 48/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 10.0738 - acc: 0.3750
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 49/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 11.5849 - acc: 0.2812
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 50/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.0886 - acc: 0.2500
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 51/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 11.5849 - acc: 0.2812
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 52/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 13.0960 - acc: 0.1875
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 53/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 13.0960 - acc: 0.1875
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 54/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 10.5775 - acc: 0.3438
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 30us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 55/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.5923 - acc: 0.2188
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 56/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 11.5849 - acc: 0.2812
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 57/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 13.0960 - acc: 0.1875
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 58/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.5923 - acc: 0.2188
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 59/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 14.6070 - acc: 0.0938
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 60/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.5923 - acc: 0.2188
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 61/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.0886 - acc: 0.2500
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 62/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 13.5996 - acc: 0.1562
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 30us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 63/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 13.0960 - acc: 0.1875
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 64/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 11.5849 - acc: 0.2812
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 65/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 10.5775 - acc: 0.3438
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 66/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 9.5701 - acc: 0.4062
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 67/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 13.5996 - acc: 0.1562
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 68/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 13.5996 - acc: 0.1562
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 69/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.0886 - acc: 0.2500
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 70/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 14.6070 - acc: 0.0938
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 30us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 71/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.5923 - acc: 0.2188
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 72/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.5923 - acc: 0.2188
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 73/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.0886 - acc: 0.2500
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 73us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 74/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 11.0812 - acc: 0.3125
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 75/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.0886 - acc: 0.2500
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 76/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 14.1033 - acc: 0.1250
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 77/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.0886 - acc: 0.2500
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 78/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 14.1033 - acc: 0.1250
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 79/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 11.5849 - acc: 0.2812
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 30us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 80/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 11.0812 - acc: 0.3125
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 81/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 10.0738 - acc: 0.3750
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 82/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.5923 - acc: 0.2188
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 83/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.5923 - acc: 0.2188
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 84/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.0886 - acc: 0.2500
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 85/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 10.5775 - acc: 0.3438
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 86/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.5923 - acc: 0.2188
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 30us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 87/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 13.5996 - acc: 0.1562
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 30us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 88/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 13.0960 - acc: 0.1875
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 89/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 13.0960 - acc: 0.1875
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 90/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.0886 - acc: 0.2500
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 91/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.0886 - acc: 0.2500
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 92/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 14.6070 - acc: 0.0938
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 30us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 93/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 10.5775 - acc: 0.3438
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331
Epoch 94/320

 32/519 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 14.1033 - acc: 0.1250
519/519 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 12.3603 - acc: 0.2331

***************REST OF TRAINING REMOVED DUE TO WORD LIMIT*****************

==================================================
ACCURACY TESTING

 32/130 [======>.......................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 12.5923 - acc: 0.2188
130/130 [==============================] - 0s 481us/sample - loss: 13.0185 - acc: 0.1923
Test accuracy: 0.1923077
==================================================
CLASSIFICATION
PREDICTION:  5-10M
ACTUAL:  500K-1M

PREDICTION:  5-10M
ACTUAL:  101-500K

PREDICTION:  5-10M
ACTUAL:  25-50M

PREDICTION:  5-10M
ACTUAL:  1-5M

PREDICTION:  5-10M
ACTUAL:  10-25M

PREDICTION:  5-10M
ACTUAL:  10-25M

PREDICTION:  5-10M
ACTUAL:  25-50M

PREDICTION:  5-10M
ACTUAL:  5-10M

PREDICTION:  5-10M
ACTUAL:  1-5M

PREDICTION:  5-10M
ACTUAL:  1-5M

==================================================
END
```

Comment: MNIST is a Computer Vision problem dataset, your data is well structured and neural networks are not the best approach to it. Try XGBoost or Random Forests and you will probably get better results.

Answer (score 1):

There are many potential issues that could cause this. What I would do is actually look at the training set you have created (write it to a csv perhaps) and make sure that everything is populating as expected. Is there a roughly equal distribution of all of the different potential classes? Do you have a good amount of data for each different categorical variable (in your case, player positions)? You only have 519 samples to choose from, perhaps you should simplify things down first by just doing a logistic regression and seeing if that works. Regardless, to get anything worthwhile I would recommend that you acquire more data, as it appears you only have at best 50 examples per each class.